# After downloading JAVA code from Github, the class files are always locked and I am never able to compile or run my code

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

[This shows the locked class files that keep me from compiling and running my programs after downloading code from Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcNr1.png)

I am a first-year college student and I have been using IntelliJ for Java programming and I always have to copy and paste the code into new files if I want to run my programs after downloading them from GitHub. The problem is that the class files are always locked after download and I can't set up a run configuration.

Is there a way to have IntelliJ automatically set up a configuration whenever I download my code from GitHub? Or is there a way to at least unlock the classes so I can set up a run configuration.

Comment: instead of downloading and import you can directly import the project from git and check;

Answer (score 1):

There's a small padlock button at the bottom right of IntelliJ-IDEA. You can lock/unlock files using that button.

[image]